# Why is the Execution Units in the Sandy Bridge MicroArchitecture connected to the Scheduler and the ReOrder buffer?

Tags: cpu, processor

I am reading [Sandy Bridge MicroArchitecture description](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/microarchitectures/sandy_bridge_(client)#Scheduler_Ports_.26_Execution_Units) and I do not understand why the Execution Units are connected to the Scheduler and the ReOrder buffer.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Can't you format your code to understand clearly

Comment: @DulajKulathunga what do you mean? There is no code